# Como usar o comando "print" para mostrar variáveis em string junto com inteiros em MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Eu estou fazendo um exercício no MATLAB, mas sempre me deparo com um erro sobre a sintaxe da função `print`, ele fala que não consigo colocar strings e inteiros juntos para serem mostrados, mas já vi exemplos parecidos

Segue o código

```
meses = ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'];

mes = input('Valor de 1 a 12');

if 1 <=mes<=12

print('o Mês correspondente é', meses(mes))

else

print('o calendário só tem 12 meses')

end
```

Como seria a sintaxe correta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta isso:

```
meses = {'Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'};
mesdata = cellstr(meses)

prompt = 'Valor de 1 a 12: ';
mes = input(prompt);
%mes=13;
if (mes >= 1) && (mes <= 12)
            disp(strcat('o Mês correspondente é' ,{': '}, mesdata(1,mes)));
        else
            disp('o calendário só tem 12 meses');
        end
```